# Launch tomcat as service

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have a question, currently my webapp are launched as the service. They have added the webapp in the init.d and all app have an entry in init.d. For me this way is bad

So for each webapp I have new process launched.

Tomcat engine should start as service and launch all the webapp, am'I wrong ? If you have any ressource to help me please follow me links.

Thanks

Comment: No, very often you have a tomcat per webapp (so that you can easily recycle them independently), but all your Tomcat instances are behind a single Apache or Nginx server.

Comment: But what is the best way to go ? 1 webserver for all webapp should be the rigth way no ? because currently there is X process tomcat for X webapp.

Comment: No hard rules, but very often it is one tomcat per webapp, because it's easier to manage. Thereis also the trend to drop Tomcat and use SpringBoot (more suitable for containers)(and it's also one container per webapp).

Comment: Yes I 'am agree with you but one tomcat for one webapp it's only for container like docker, but I have never saw one tomcat for one webapp for classic install tomcat or using archive tomcat. It's very heavy for the system to create one tomcat process for one webapp and it's heavy to manage if you use web-gui console manager. It's like opening 10 words instance to create 10 pages.

Comment: Do you want an advice or do you want a confirmation that you are right?

Comment: Sorry but I must to learn more challenge what the people said on internet I have checked official apache web site but I have found any ressource on that point, all the ressource says what there is one instance. If you have any documentation on that I'll be happy to read it

Comment: There is no need to challenge. Sometimes it is useful/necessary to have multiple instances, sometimes not. Either solution is not 100% wrong, it depends on many factors.